# what test for analysing level of agreement of users perception on species population trends from ordinal categorical data

Tags: categorical-data, model-selection, multilevel-analysis, test-for-trend

This is my first post ever so I beg you please forgive me any mistake (I'm also super newbie in stats). 
I have this dataset that comes from interviews filled by users (divers) about their perception on resources (six shark species) population trends across four decades. Every user was asked to state their perception of population trend for every shark based on five categories: major decrease, decrease, estable, increase, and major increase. They were asked to constrain their answers per decade: trend for species X within decade 80s, trend for the same species within 90s, 00s, etc for the rest species. Worth to note that the amount of answers per decade varied according to the level of experience of divers, which means that there were more divers with experience toward the last two decades, and just few since the 80s (a total of four divers with experience since 80s; 14 since 90s; and, 25 since 2000s). I have attached a figure on the answers of those 25 divers on one shark species.

[Obtained scores from interviewing divers about an X shark species population trend across the last four decades. Answers obtained from 25 divers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OD2XU.png)

[image]

I've been looking for the simplest way to assess their level of agreement in any specific trend across decades. Find out that ANOVAs are no near a good way to assess any type of categorical data and literature redirected me into logic mixed models, although I still don't have clear the picture how those will let me assess level of agreement and overall species trends across time. Could anybody please give some light to my analysis and tell me which should be the best statistical test to assess level of agreement and trends across time of this dataset? Will logic mixed models work for this? 
Please, I use R so I would like to kindly request your help and point me in any specific R routine/package. Also, if there is anything I should add to make my question clearer, please do let me know.

Comment: Hey guys... just poking... does anybody have an idea how to? should I rephrase the question? Cheers, C.